# Filter from a string to a string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, filter

This is the head() of my data frame:

```
date        id_station  zona  media_diaria max_diaria min_diaria sd_diaria count
2019-01-01  AJM         SO           0.339        0.5        0.2     0.114    18
2019-01-01  ATI         NO           0.439        0.9        0.2     0.238    18
2019-01-01  BJU         CE           0.667        1          0.4     0.235    18
2019-01-01  CAM         NO           0.611        1.2        0.2     0.356    18
2019-01-01  CCA         SO           0.55         0.8        0.3     0.195    18
2019-01-01  CHO         SE           0.541        1.6        0.1     0.511    17
```

What I am trying to do is to filter the data frame from March 1st, 2019 (2019-03-01) to February 29, 2020 (2020-02-29).

I have tried the following:

```
df <- df %>%
      filter(date %in% c(2019-03-01:2020-02-29))
```

But it always returns an empty data frame. So I tried doing it but treating the dates as strings:

```
df <- df %>%
      filter(date %in% c('2019-03-01':'2020-02-29'))
```

But it too returns an empty data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `between`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(between(date, as.Date('2019-03-01'), as.Date('2020-02-29')))
```